# How to output unlimited RSS Feed items

Tags: rss

How can I completely disable the limit on feed items in my RSS feed that WordPress generates? I know you can modify the limit but I want to programmatically disable the limit completely.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, as [wp-includes/feed-rss2.php](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php) is written, there are no ways of doing such thing by using a feed-page-specific hook or filter, so you have to either:

1. Edit this file manually (which will be broken after every update)
2. Make a page template with the same content and changing the query arguments before the loop runs (will generate different URLs, not a good choice but it works as expected)
3. Alter query arguments if the page is a feed. (By using a general hook, like pre_get_posts)

I will explain the 3rd way:

```
function feed_unlimited_posts( $query ){
       if(is_feed())
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
       return $vars;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'feed_unlimited_posts' );
```

**Please Note**: I haven't done testing on this piece of code, if you did and it worked, please suggest an edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the query.

For a feed you need to set [`posts_per_rss`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1889).
"-1" for unlimited didn't worked for me, so I just used a large number (feeds are always paged, if I see it correctly).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_feed_set_posts_per_rss' ); 

function custom_feed_set_posts_per_rss( $query ){
       if($query->is_feed){
            $query->set( 'posts_per_rss', 1000 );
       }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample of generating RSS in a template style.

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: Article Feed
*/
$numposts = 10; // number of posts in feed
$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts.'&cat=3');
$more = 1;

header('Content-Type: '.feed_content_type('rss-http').'; charset='.get_option('blog_charset'), true);
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>';
?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>
<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?> - Article Feed</title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss("description") ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <?php the_generator( 'rss2' ); ?>
    <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
        <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
        <comments><?php comments_link(); ?></comments>
        <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
        <dc:creator><?php the_author(); ?></dc:creator>
<?php the_category_rss(); ?>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
<?php if (get_option('rss_use_excerpt')) : ?>

        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
<?php else : ?>

        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
    <?php if ( strlen( $post->post_content ) > 0 ) : ?>

        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_content() ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php else : ?>

        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

        <wfw:commentRss><?php echo get_post_comments_feed_link(); ?></wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></slash:comments>
<?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
<?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>

    </item>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

In this code the no. of post is limited to 10 of one particular category. I hope you need to work around in order to fulfill your need.

If you also generate your own query (possibly using wp_query) and then use the returned array to fill the fields for the RSS

For reference: [Digging WP's article on customizing RSS feeds](http://digwp.com/2012/10/customizing-wordpress-feeds/)

P.S: code not tested.

Comment: It is not necessary to create a new feed include markup. A change of the query for the feed is enough and makes not necessary to maintain the feed markup.